# Terminate the app running in background after a specific time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Can I terminate the app running in background after a specific time? Eg: after runing app 24hrs in background, i want to kill the app. then, when you launch the app, app should load as fresh..(like viewDidLoad ..)

Can I do this in iOS?

Comment: s possible i not tried yet   use this  exit(0); next time opens as fresh....

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in other discussion, terminating your app might get your app refused by Apple.

It's not really an answer, but you could simply override

> - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

to save the date when the user exit your app.

> - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

And compare the current date with the last one to know if you should restart your app or not.
By restart your app i presenting your user your first UIViewController (and potentially cleaning some data).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did hv research about this scenario also, There is a risk of rejecting the app???

Comment: It's ok if you just present the first VC on applicationWillEnterForeground: without killing the app. If it reassures you, i have multiple applications on the AppStore that does it.

Comment: But be careful, depending on your app you might have to re-init some cached data.